# I require some advice with

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, chained-payments

I could not found any related answers or advice. My question is advice related, can a South-African citizen use PayPal chained adaptive process, as the process requires you PayPal account to be upgraded to a pro account that requires USA citizenship?

Answer (score 0):

For Pro account, you need to have a valid US address.